# Context API reducer with fetch() doesn't update state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fetch, react-context

I'm working on a login function in e-commerce React app using Context API.
So when user types in his e-mail and password that calls an action in reducer to check that data and set user data as state in Context Provider.

Here's the action (I'm ommitting other cases that work):

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
...

switch(action.type) {
case 'USER_LOGIN': 
        let user = userLogin(state.user,action.payload);
        return {
          ...state,
          user: user,
          loggedIn: temp.length> 0 ? true: false
        };

...
```

Here's the function `userLogin()` which itself works fine and returns a nice array of user data.

```
var userLogin = (user, payload) => {

  const url = "/api/users/login.php";
  console.log(payload);
  fetch(url,{
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(payload)
  })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
      (result) => {
          user.id = result.id;
          user.name = result.name;
          user.email = result.email;
          user.phone = result.phone;
          user.city = result.city;
          user.street = result.street;
          user.building = result.building;
          user.flat = result.flat;        
      },
      (error) => {
          console.log(error);
      }); 
  return user;
}
```

But when in result in my `<Provider>` the value of state of `user` stays an empty array as initialized.

I think that there's something that has to work with asyncronous type of that `fetch()`, but couldn't find any reference about that.

UPD: this is my `<Login>` component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Consumer} from '../../Context'


export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: "",
            password: "",
        };
    }

    userLogin = (dispatch, e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch({
            type: 'USER_LOGIN',
            payload: {email: this.state.email,
                      password: this.state.password }
        });
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Consumer>
            {
                value=> {
                    const {dispatch} = value;
                    return (
                        <div className="checkout__container">
                        <h5 className="checkout__header">Login</h5>
                        <form>
                            <label className="checkout__label">E-mail:</label><br />
                            <input className="checkout__input" type="email" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange}></input><br /><br />
                            <label className="checkout__label">Password:</label><br />
                            <input className="checkout__input" type="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange}></input><br /><br />
                            <button type="button" className="button button-primary" onClick={this.userLogin.bind(this, dispatch)}>Sign In</button>

                        </form> 
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }


            </Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

UPD #2: Here's extract from my `Context.js`  with `Provider` component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Context = React.createContext();

const reducer = (state, action) => {
...
switch(action.type) {
case 'USER_LOGIN': 
        let user = userLogin(state.user,action.payload);
        return {
          ...state,
          user: user
        };
  }; 
};

var userLogin = (user, payload) => {
    // Do fetch() here and return user array
}
...
class Provider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          user: [],
          loggedIn: false,
          dispatch: action => this.setState( state => reducer(state,action))         
        };
    }
 render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
          {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    )
  }
}

const Consumer = Context.Consumer;

export {Provider, Consumer};
```

Comment: `fetch` is `async`. So `userLogin()` returns immediately without changing the `user` object. I don't think a reducer is the right place to load data asynchronously. Use something like `thunk`, `saga` or `observables` to handle side effects.

Comment: `thunk` and `saga` work with `Redux`, and `observables` are referred to `RxJS`. Is there a way to implement `async` `fetch` using `Context API`?

Comment: Why cant you `fetch` and then `dispatch` the action ?

Comment: @AsafAviv - you mean `fetch` in the `<Login>` component and then pass the data to `<Provider>`? Is this a good patern? I'm doing all other `fetch`es in my `context.js` and and there manage my "global state" passing data to components.

Comment: @AsafAviv I'm not using `Redux` at all, only `Context API`.
Added `<Login>` сomponent above

Comment: How did you configured `Provider`? Can you please share code of component where `Provider` is located

Comment: @Fyodor - added my `Context.js` contents.

Comment: I think that I shoud use `useEffect()` hook for my `userLogin()` function

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is here

```
var userLogin = (user, payload) => {
    //...
    fetch(url,{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            user.id = result.id;
            user.name = result.name;
            // ...     
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }); 
    return user;
}
```

You call `fetch` which returns Promise. When Promise will be resolved, callback passed to `then` will be called. But `userLogin` will not stop execution until Promise is resolved. So just after `fetch` called, `userLogin` returns. But `user` is not changed at that time. Response not received and Promise is not resolved.

When response comes, `user` will be changed but `return` statement has already been executed, so nothing will be returned.

The only way how to correct this is to follow idea of Redux and move async code to action creator. In your case action creator is `userLogin` from `Login` component and leave reducer code fully synchronious. You may also move `userLogin` method out from `Login` component.

For example

```
userLogin = (dispatch, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let payload = {email: this.state.email,
                  password: this.state.password };
    const url = "/api/users/login.php";
    console.log(payload);
    fetch(url,{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            user.id = result.id;
            user.name = result.name;
            // ...
            // And call dispatch from here
            dispatch (type: 'USER_LOGIN',
                user: user // We don't need payload here as we already got user info
            );
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }); 
}
```

And modify reducer accordinately

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
//...
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'USER_LOGIN': 
            return {
                ...state,
                user: [...user, action.user]; // user is array so add new user to existing array
            };
    }; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get user array passed to `reducer`, but `state` is set to an empty array instead of `action.user`.
`case 'USER_LOGIN': return { ...state, user: action.user  };`
I replace `user` with `action.user` because it's the user logged in, there should be only one.

Comment: What are the contents of `user` before dispatch call?

Comment: I tried 2 ways: `user: []` and `user:undefined` in `Provider` `state`.
The first doesn't change after `dispatch`, and second sets `user` to and empty array

Comment: Much more important what is passed to dispatch. Please `console.log(user)` before calling dispatch

Comment: before calling dispatch `user` is an array with correct user data returned from database. The same is when `console.log(action.user)` in the `reducer()`